# Is the value of the privateFor param accesible in the contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, quorum

Transaction params for quorum can contain a `privateFor` param

```
{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"eth_sendTransaction",
    "params":[
        {
            "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
            "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
            "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400
            "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
            "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
            "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675",
            "privateFor": ["$PUBKEY1, $PUBKEY2"]
        }
    ],
    "id":1
}
```

How can the `privateFor` param be accessed from the solidity contract code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, privateFor is never passed or recorder on chain or into EVM, therefore, it is impossible to read privateFor in a contract